# Tapestry 5 component trouble

Tags: java, tapestry

This is part of a much bigger problem I am trying to solve, but some idea of logic on how to do this would help me work out the rest of what I need.

I was wondering if it's possible to have the user select from a list of components, and then to show that component on the page?

For example, if I have 3 links:

```
[Component 1]
[Component 2]
[Component 3]
```

If the user selects "Component 1", I would like the page to refresh and show that component on the page. I want to avoid having to create a separate page for each component. The issue I have is that if I use something like this in the template (.tml):

```
<t:tools.HelloComponent> </t:tools.HelloComponent>
```

Then it is hard coded to always show that one component. I can't change the .tml file at runtime because that will affect all users.

I'm not sure what the best logic is for this, so i'm just looking for some general guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [Blocks](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/Block.html) are what you want to use.

A block is basically a chunk of markup within a template which does not automatically render, but which can be referenced in the Java and rendered on demand.

So in your case, you might want to put each component inside its own block inside the page template, and use something like the [Delegate](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Delegate.html) component to render the correct block, which you decide in a method in the page Java (returning one of the `@Inject`-ed blocks)

**Page .tml**

```
<t:block id="blockA">
    <t:tools.Component1 />
</t:block>

<t:block id="blockB">
    <t:tools.Component2 />
</t:block>

<t:block id="blockC">
    <t:tools.Component3 />
</t:block>

<t:delegate to="blockToRender"/> // chosen block will actually render here
```

**Page Java**

```
public class YourPage {

    @Inject private Block blockA;
    @Inject private Block blockB;
    @Inject private Block blockC;

    public Object getBlockToRender() {
        Block blockToRender;
        // logic here to set blockToRender to blockA, blockB or blockC
        return blockToRender
    }
}
```

Without knowing exactly what you want to do on your page it's hard to be more specific about the implementation where the comment is, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning the [block binding prefix](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters.html#ComponentParameters-BindingExpressions) here too